# My App Inside WhatsApp's Share Extension

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, whatsapp

Hello when i am in WhatsApp and i want share a image, its going to open Share Extension with many apps like Slack. And when i am in App Photos and i want share a image, its going to opens Share Extension with apps like Flicker but isn't Slack. So my question is, can i add my own app to Whatsapp's Share Extension? and How can i catch it in my own app with Swift?

[image: WhatsApp]
[image: App Photos]

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. So actually it will not be your main app,but it will be an extension to your main app. 
Share extensions are made for the exact same purpose.
Kindly check for "Share Extension"
Following link may help you.
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Share.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH12-SW1